# WPF Best Practice Coming From Windows Forms

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have extensive WinForms experience, but am new to WPF. Implementing Form design vision through XAML was easy enouhg to delve into, but I'm still a little unclear on what is expected from the M-V-VM programming style. I understand the principle of separating how things look from how they behave, but doing so sensibly in some cases continues to elude me.

For example, if I have a keypad with 9 buttons, and I want a means of enabling/disabling all of them through their IsEnable property, the Form designer in me wants to address them all in a code-behind method targeting them by Design Name. What is the WPF equivalent of such an operation? Am I expected to manage a series of bools in codebehind, and bind each one in the XAML to each  respective button attribute? Thanks for any guidance. If this one scenario is explained, it should be sufficient to point me in the right direction

Comment: In your one case: It's one of the things MVVM really excels at: You want to create a class "Window1ViewModel" and a parent container of your buttons to your ViewModel's IsEnabled property that you've created yourself. However, there's some none-trivial issues with MVVM that (imho) doesn't really have a strong solution - one of them being dialogs.
My suggestion to you is to disable the designer and work in pure XAML, much like you wouldn't do much html in a WYSIWYG editor. Once you get a grasp of things, you might want to re-enable the designer.

Comment: http://reedcopsey.com/series/windows-forms-to-mvvm/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That specific problem is easily solved with binding. You would bind your buttons `IsEnabled` property to a public Property in your `ViewModel` and based on the logic contained in your `ViewModel` when that property value is changed your keypad button would get enabled or disabled.

As @GCamel mentioned you could also have a POCO class that would represent your button which would implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface with one of the properties being the IsEnabled property. You would add instances of this class to an `ObservableCollection` and when that IsEnabled property changes your button would become enabled or disabled in the UI.

I would also strongly recommend using one of the MVVM frameworks, my personal favorite is [Simple MVVM Toolkit](https://simplemvvmtoolkit.codeplex.com/) by Tony Sneed who also has a great article about the dialogs problem mentioned by @cwap [Climb Onboard on the MVVM Message Bus](https://blog.tonysneed.com/2011/03/03/climb-onboard-on-the-mvvm-message-bus/)

Comment: thanks for all the links!

Answer (score 1):

ideally, you would have an observable collection of button_info with IsEnabled property, icon and text - bind the collection to whathever suitable control like itemsControl, list, or grid and associate your button_info to a datatemple...you see what i mean ? no gui, no gui, just viewmodel and binding

or like [this sample ???](https://github.com/mesta1/WPF-on-screen-keyboard-and-keypad/blob/master/KeyPad/KeyPad/Keypad.xaml)